# Vba that will only select rows where cells in column are marked "x"

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for VBA code that will look at a specific column like A and only select the rows that have certain cells that are marked with an "x".

Comment: Use `.AutoFilter` Range Object Method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SelectRow()
Dim columnRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Set columnRange = Range("A:A")

For Each c In columnRange 'For every cell in column a
    If InStr(1, c, "x") Then 'If cell contains "x" then
        c.EntireRow.Select 'Select row
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

*.Autofilter* method

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:D").AutoFilter
        .Range("A:z").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=x
End With
```